# Firefox SDK access preferences from content script

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

### About

I'm working on a Firefox Add-on using the Firefox Add-on SDK. The add-on will be site specific and it will hide certain elements based on user preferences.

I already made this add-on a few years back, but with the new SDK things work a bit different.

### Code

Because the add-on is site specific and I need to modify the content of the site I use the '**PageMod**' module

[**main.js**]

```
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.ipvisie.com",
  contentScriptFile: [
    data.url('jquery-1.11.1.min.js'),
    data.url('script.js')
  ]
});
```

This works great, jQuery is implemented and I can add and run javascript from script.js

I have declared the preferences in '**package.json**' and this works great. I can access this from '**main.js**'

### Problem

My problem is that the ContentScript doesn't have access to the user preferences.

How can I gain access to the current preferences in my ContentScript '**script.js**'?

### Tried attempts

**Attempt 1**
First thing I tried was just to request the preference from the ContentScript

```
if (require('sdk/simple-prefs').prefs['somePreference'] == true) {
    alert('Pref checked');
}
```

**Attempt 2**
I read in the documentation that some read only parameters can be send with the ContentScript. This seemed to work, but when I changed my preferences the values were already set. Only if I would restart the browser the correct setting would be passed.

```
contentScriptOptions: {
    advertLink: require('sdk/simple-prefs').prefs['advertTop'],
    advertDay: require('sdk/simple-prefs').prefs['advertDay'],
    advertAdmart: require('sdk/simple-prefs').prefs['advertAdmart'],
    advertLink: require('sdk/simple-prefs').prefs['advertLink']
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should send the new preferences to the content script every time preferences got changed and not only at the scripts initialisation.

You can communicate with the content script via messages: [Communicating With Content Scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#Communicating_With_Content_Scripts)
Create a function that receives changed preference names and values and a [preference change listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs#on%28prefName.2C_listener%29) to send the changes to the script:

```
pageMod.PageMod({
  // ...
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    worker.port.on("prefChange", function(prefName, prefValue) {
      // update page ...
    });

    function onPrefChange(prefName) {
      self.port.emit("prefChange", prefName, require("sdk/simple-prefs").prefs[prefName]);
    }
    require("sdk/simple-prefs").on("", onPrefChange);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've succesfully messaged a preferance.
But I can't find out how to combine the message with onPrefChange.

Comment: I jjst found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10168577/897024 - Apparently you have to put the `prefChange` listener in the `onAttach` function. I updated the answer but I can't really test it right now

Comment: I've achieved it and I'm pretty sure your edited answer will work asswell.

I stored the worker in a variable so I can access it with my 'onPrefChange' function outside of 'onAttach'